# Compilation error: Statement with no effect

Tags: c, for-loop

```c
dspList_t *pDspMng = NULL;

for(pDspMng = SDSPMNG; pDspMng->mesfct != NULL && strcmp (pDspMng->mesfct, mesfct); pDspMng->prec);
```

```
INTdspmng.sc: In function 'WebCallback':
INTdspmng.sc:216:9: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
         for(pDspMng = SDSPMNG; pDspMng->mesfct != NULL && strcmp (pDspMng->mesfct, mesfct); pDspMng->prec);
```

This loop is still waiting for a new mesfct for that i make ";" after for, i want an infinite loop

Comment: What are `dspList_t ` and `SDSPMNG`? Who updates `mesfct`? Another thread?

Comment: Your for loop does not make sense. You iterate but nothing changes from one iteration to the next. So, either you iterate only once (but without changing anything to anything) if the condition part is false, or you iterate forever without any side-effect, which is plain useless.

Comment: @Renaud how can i correct it ? , i want an infinite loop

Comment: @Jabberwocky : dsplist_t is a structure and SDSPMNG is a pointer to structure and mesfct updates by a webserver

Comment: @slamamohamed please [edit] the question and put all relevant information into the question. Show the declaration of the relevant structs and tell us what this "web server" is. Is it a thread? This "webserver updating `mesfect`" sounds very fishy.

Comment: @slamamohamed Oh, I see, your `pDspMng->mesfct` is updated by an external webserver and you are waiting for an external event to happen. Well, this is a special case that cannot really be handled the way you think. You must first tell the compiler such that it does not optimize away your apparently useless code. Have a look at the `volatile` qualifier. Next you must realize that looping like this is extremely inefficient. (unless what you are interested in is using your computer as a heating device).

Comment: @slamamohamed The right question to ask yourself is how fast you want to react on the event you wait for? Minutes, seconds, milliseconds, micro-seconds, less? Depending on the answer you can use some techniques or not. In case you want to react in matter of seconds you should insert a sleep statement in your loop to let your micro-processor do some other useful job while waiting. If you need super-fast reactions your C program alone is probably not the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pDspMng->prec` is practically useless. You're computing the value but doing nothing with that value. You may want to store the value in some variable, maybe like `pDspMng = pDspMng->prec`

Also, the `;` at the end of the `for` loop looks erroneous.

Comment: `pDspMng->prec` is not only _practically_ useless. It is just plain useless.

Comment: how can we browse a linked list ?

Comment: i make pDspMng = pDspMng->prec and the problem resolved

Comment: @Jabberwocky better wordings. :P